# how to get Rolename from existing Lambda function on cloud via its friendly name or arn using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

I have created a CFN template for rotating secret of RDS. It consist of a AWS HostedLambda which calls for an autogenerated Role. I want to attach another policy to that role.

```
  rRotationLambdaDecryptPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    DependsOn: rSecretRotationScheduleHostedRotationLambda
    Properties:
      Description: "Providing access to HostedLambda for decrypting KMS"
      ManagedPolicyName: CustomedHostedLambdaKmsUserRolePolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Sid: AllowLambdaDecryptKMS
          Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - kms:Decrypt
            - kms:CreateGrant
          Resource:
          - !Sub arn:aws:kms:*:${AWS::AccountId}:key/*
          Condition:
            ForAnyValue:StringLike:
              kms:ResourceAliases: alias/SecretsManager_KMSKey
      Roles: <friendly rolename>
```

Problem is i know the Lambda friendly name and its Arn. Need to find the rolename linked to this lambda so that i can attach the above policy to it(Add its friendly name to Roles).

tried attaching this below

```
      Roles: 
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - '"'
            - Fn::GetAtt:
              - !Sub 'arn:aws:lambda::${AWS::AccountId}:function:SecretsManager-research-creds-rotation-lambda'
              - Role
            - '"'
```

P.S.- cant use importvalue here, because the nested stack has been created by AWS and its output doesn't consist of export.

Lambda used:-

```
  rSecretRotationSchedule:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::RotationSchedule
    Properties:
      SecretId:<SecretId>
      HostedRotationLambda:
        KmsKeyArn: <KmsKeyArn>
        MasterSecretArn: <MasterSecretArn>
        MasterSecretKmsKeyArn: <MasterSecretKmsKeyArn>
        RotationType: PostgreSQLMultiUser
        RotationLambdaName: SecretsManager-research-creds-rotation-lambda
        VpcSecurityGroupIds: <VpcSecurityGroupIds>
        VpcSubnetIds: <VpcSubnetIds>
      RotationRules:
        AutomaticallyAfterDays: 60
```

Below is the link from which i took reference for template:-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-rotationschedule.html

Comment: Can you share the template used to create the lambda? And I assume that your template is a different template than the one the lambda is created in, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is HostedLambda being called & created by AWS.

Comment: have updated the question with doc links!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you can't do this with plain CFN. You would have to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). This would be in the form of a new lambda function which would use AWS SDK to query attributes of your primary lambda function. Once the custom resource finds the role name it would return it to your stack for further use.